# How to draw strip-line as background

Tags: android, background, android-imageview

Is there any way to draw 'strip-lines' as background in android?

---

**Attachment with picture for better illustration: (Youtube App)**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "tiling" a small pattern image ?

Comment: @user117 Tell me more about that :)

Comment: @Roylee - Try creating a small icon of the stripe pattern that you like. Then just repeat it horizontally, and vertically and it should fill up any size with stripes.

Comment: refer this code google io also use this type of pattern https://code.google.com/p/iosched/ thi sis the best example

Comment: @DixitPatel Yeah I have seen that, so how does it helps ? :)

Comment: Just go into res-> layout-large-land-v11 folder in this code you will find activity_home.xml file in this file google io use this type of pattern in background

Comment: OKay, I think I've got it now! Thanks for your input, I'm sure others would benefit from this :) @DixitPatel

Comment: create a 9-patch png and set as background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Example:

Add a `wood_pattern.xml` to `res/drawable/` :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/bg_wood"
                android:tileMode="repeat"
                android:dither="true"
                android:antialias="true"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

set this as background:

```
android:background="@drawable/wood_pattern"
```

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If u are using imageview and want to set border here is the code (i have set black background):

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/red_minus_icon"
android:background="#000000"
android:padding="1dp"/>
```

Comment: Any idea what is red_minus_icon?

Comment: if u r not using imageview can u plz specify which control of UI u r using?

Comment: NO problem I can have an imageview, what is a red_minus_icon anyway? a strip-line image?

Comment: thats the image u want to show in imageview . if u want to set via code u can use : ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);        
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

Comment: I do know how to set an image as background, the question is how to have a strip-lines as background.

Comment: android:padding="1dp" & android:background="#000000" thats shows me back-strip on imageview